# I have calculated distance and time in an innerHTML and I can not pass it using the id in a textbox. How can I fix that?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, textbox, innerhtml

I am setting time and distance in an innerHTML field but I want to show it inside a textbox. I Am really new to javascript and while innerHTML works ok I think its better to show this info in a box. Any ideas?

```
    var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
    var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value;
    var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
    duration = parseFloat(duration / 60).toFixed(2);
    dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
    dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
    dvDistance.innerHTML += "Time:" + duration + " min";
```

This is how I call it but while I tried with `<input>` I couldn't show up result.

```
    <div id="dvDistance"></div>
```

Comment: Did you want a [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) or an [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) with your text in it?

Comment: basically i dont know what is better but i thing an <input> would be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [HTML Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) doesn't have `.innerHTML`, it uses `.value` for the text.  Change the `.innerHTML` to `.value` and remove the HTML tags from the string.

[image: resulting output]

**code snippet:**

```js
var distance = 20
var duration = 60
var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
duration = parseFloat(duration / 60).toFixed(2);
dvDistance.value = "";
dvDistance.value += "Distance: " + distance + " ";
dvDistance.value += "Time: " + duration + " min";
```

```html
<input id="dvDistance" size="30" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the border and width property of the div in CSS to add a box around it.

```js
var distance = 20
var duration = 60
var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
duration = parseFloat(duration / 60).toFixed(2);
dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
dvDistance.innerHTML += "Time: " + duration + " min";
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 7em;
}
```

```html
<div id="dvDistance" class="box"></div>
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: thanks for the feedback and updating my answer..i am not familiar with javascript and css and i couldnt find any other resource..i am still showin a  black line_____ before value gets in the box. is it possible to get it hidden somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the `class="box"` property from the div (in HTML) and when you want to show the box you just do `dvDistance.className = "box"`

Comment: you mean in the id i will write that?
man...i suck at HTML and CSS

Comment: If you have the `box` class in CSS then you can do `dvDistance.className = "box"` or `document.getElementById("dvDistance").className = "box"` to add a border around it.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the third line should be
`var dvDistance = document.getElementById("#dvDistance");`

Comment: That does not answer the question. He said his current code works but he wants it to be in a box.